# Unable to stop java process using SIGINT on Linux

Tags: java, signals, amazon-dynamodb, ubuntu-16.04

I am building a virtual machine for some tests that needs to run among other things DynamoDb web service. VM is based on stock Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

This is the part of provisioning script that installs DynamoDB:

```sh
# Install local instance of DynamoDB
DARCHFILE='/tmp/dynamodb_local_latest.zip'
wget -P /tmp/ -nv https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb-local/dynamodb_local_latest.zip
sudo unzip -q "$DARCHFILE" -d /usr/local/lib/dynamodb
sudo mkdir -pv /var/lib/dynamodb/
sudo mkdir -pv /var/log/dynamodb/

sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
```

This is the script that executes DynamoDb:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# -*- mode: sh -*-
# vi: set ft=sh :

java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib/dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal_lib/ \
     -jar /usr/local/lib/dynamodb/DynamoDBLocal.jar \
     -dbPath /var/lib/dynamodb/ \
     -optimizeDbBeforeStartup \
     -port 8000 > /var/log/dynamodb/trace.log 2> /var/log/dynamodb/error.log &
echo $! > /var/run/dynamodb.pid
```

Now if I try to stop the process using the "nice one" SIGINT (equivalent of Ctrl+C) it does nothing. Only sending SIGTERM works.

So this does nothing:

```sh
sudo kill -s SIGINT $(< /var/run/dynamodb.pid)
```

As we can confirm by executing this:

```sh
sudo ps -x | grep $(< /var/run/dynamodb.pid)
```

While this works just fine:

```sh
sudo kill -s SIGTERM $(< /var/run/dynamodb.pid)
```

On the other hand if I start dynamodb manually and don't send it to the background Ctrl+C does work.

So what gives? Is it my mistake or behavior by design?

Thanks

Comment: Java catches SIGINT and some other signals, in order to run shutdown  hooks.  Unfortunately, poorly written shutdown hooks can prevent Java exit altogether.  The `-Xrs` option will give you the ability to stop a Java process with SIGINT.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html.

Comment: But I want to execute those shutdown hooks in order to have graceful shutdown of the process - I do not wish to disable them which -Xrs does. Why is than Ctrl+C working when SIGINT does not and they should be the same?

Comment: Interestingly SIGHUP also terminates app. Is this better than SIGTERM or is it the same?

Comment: It’s normal for SIGHUP to terminate an application which doesn’t explicitly handle SIGHUP.  “HUP” stands for “hang up,” which originally referred to an unexpected modem disconnection while a process or shell was running.